# What does <ClassName>.() mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Not sure what this means but I came across this syntax in the kotlin html codebase. What does SCRIPT.() mean?

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html/blob/master/shared/src/main/kotlin/generated/gen-tag-unions.kt#L143

```
fun FlowOrPhrasingOrMetaDataContent.script(type : String? = null, src : String? = null, block : SCRIPT.() -> Unit = {}) : Unit = SCRIPT(attributesMapOf("type", type,"src", src), consumer).visit(block)
```

SCRIPT is a class - https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html/blob/master/shared/src/main/kotlin/generated/gen-tags-s.kt.

Or more generally, what does `<ClassName>.()` mean in Kotlin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875491/what-is-a-receiver-in-kotlin

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### Quick answer

```
block: SCRIPT.() -> Unit = {}
```

This represents a “**function literal with receiver”**. It’s a function parameter with a function type `() -> Unit` and `SCRIPT` as it’s **receiver**.

#### [Function Literals/Lambda with Receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver)

Kotlin supports the concept of “function literals with receivers”. It enables the access on visible methods and properties of a **receiver** of a lambda in its body *without any specific qualifiers*. This is very **similar to extension functions** in which it’s also possible to access visible members of the receiver object inside the extension.

A simple example, also one of the greatest functions in the Kotlin standard library, is`apply`:

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T { block(); return this }
```

As you can see, such a function literal with receiver is taken as the argument `block` here. This block is simply executed and the receiver (which is an instance of `T`) is returned. In action this looks as follows:

```
val foo: Bar = Bar().apply {
    color = RED
    text = "Foo"
}
```

We instantiate an object of `Bar` and call `apply` on it. The instance of `Bar` becomes the “receiver”. The `block`, passed as an argument in `{}`(lambda expression) does not need to use additional qualifiers to access and modify the shown visible properties `color` and `text`.

The concept of lambdas with receiver is also the most important feature for writing DSLs with Kotlin.

Comment: If it's so important, then couldn't it be explained a little less abstractly in the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver)? I read through this twice and still have no idea what it is trying to communicate. Your example is giving me a glimmer of hope. It seems like it's a little bit like the `With` clause from VisualBasic. Am I completely off base?

Answer (score 0):

> What does .() mean in Kotlin?

It is called a function literal (or lambda) with receiver

An example to try to explain the same:

```
data class Person(val name: String)

fun getPrefixSafely(
    prefixLength: Int,
    person: Person?,
    getPrefix: Person.(Int) -> String): String
{
    if (person?.name?.length ?: 0 < prefixLength) return ""
    return person?.getPrefix(prefixLength).orEmpty()
}

// Here is how getPrefixSafely can be called
getPrefixSafely(
    prefixLength = 2,
    person = Person("name"),
    getPrefix = { x -> this.name.take(x) }
)
```

**PS:** These functional literals with receiver types are similar to extension functions IMO.