# How to make 'this' a reference of Listener instead of the Activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a situation similar to the following example and when I call `this` it references the `Activity` not the `OnClickListener`. Is there way to make this a reference of the listener?

```
private fun onClick() = View.OnClickListener {
    // How to make 'this' a reference of OnClickListener instead of the Activity
}
```

Comment: `this` should already be the surrounding interface implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is by using the `object` syntax as opposed to lambda (although it’s a bit more noisy to use):

```
private fun onClick() = object: View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View){
        //this in the context of listener
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you’d have to wrap the implementation into another higher-order function that works with *[lambdas with receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48244776/8073652)*. Would be overkill here I think.

Comment: The object syntax worked very perfectly! I knew that one day lambda wouldn't be there for me... I just thought it would last a little longer!