# What's the recommended way to delay Kotlin's buildSequence?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to poll a paginated API and provide new items to the user as they appear.

```
fun connect(): Sequence<T> = buildSequence {
    while (true) {
        // result is a List<T>
        val result = dataSource.getFirstPage()
        yieldAll(/* the new data in `result` */)

        // Block the thread for a little bit
    }
}
```

Here's the sample usage:

```
for (item in connect()) {
    // do something as each item is made available
}
```

My first thought was to use the `delay` function, but I get this message:

> Restricted suspended functions can only invoke member or extension suspending functions on their restricted coroutine scope

This is the signature for `buildSequence`:

```
public fun <T> buildSequence(builderAction: suspend SequenceBuilder<T>.() -> Unit): Sequence<T>
```

I think this message means that I can only use the `suspend` functions in SequenceBuilder: `yield` and `yieldAll` and that using arbitrary `suspend` function calls aren't allowed.

Right now I'm using this to block the sequence building by one second after every time the API is polled:

```
val resumeTime = System.nanoTime() + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1)
while (resumeTime > System.nanoTime()) {
    // do nothing
}
```

This works, but it really doesn't seem like a good solution. Has anybody encountered this issue before?

Comment: Your current hackaround actually utilizes an entire CPU thread to 100% while the sequence is running...yikes. Use a scheduled executor + concurrent queue in the meantime.

Comment: Note that `buildSequence` can only be delayed synchronously: since the coroutine is run by an iterator, it always expects a suspension with a proper sequence element to return it as the iterator's next item. That's the reason why it `RestrictsSuspension`. Another concern, though, is that you use active wait instead of blocking the thread.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Why does it not work? Some research

When we look at `buildSequence`, we can see that it takes an `builderAction: suspend SequenceBuilder<T>.() -> Unit` as its argument. As a client of that method, you'll be able to hand on a `suspend` lambda that has `SequenceBuilder` as its receiver (read about lambda with receiver [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48244776/8073652)). 
The `SequenceBuilder` itself is annotated with `RestrictSuspension`:

```
@RestrictsSuspension
@SinceKotlin("1.1")
public abstract class SequenceBuilder<in T> ...
```

The annotation is defined and commented like this:

```
/**
 * Classes and interfaces marked with this annotation are restricted
 * when used as receivers for extension `suspend` functions. 
 * These `suspend` extensions can only invoke other member or extension     
 * `suspend` functions on this particular receiver only 
 * and are restricted from calling arbitrary suspension functions.
 */
@SinceKotlin("1.1") @Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS) @Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
public annotation class RestrictsSuspension
```

As the `RestrictSuspension` documentation tells, in the case of `buildSequence`, you can pass a lambda with `SequenceBuilder` as its receiver but with **restricted** possibilities since you'll only be able to call "other member or extension `suspend` functions on this particular receiver". That means, the block passed to `buildSequence` may call any method defined on `SequenceBuilder` (like `yield`, `yieldAll`). Since, on the other hand, the block is "restricted from calling arbitrary suspension functions", using `delay` does not work. The resulting compiler error verifies it:

> Restricted suspended functions can only invoke member or extension suspending functions on their restricted coroutine scope.

Ultimately, you need to be aware that the `buildSequence` creates a coroutine that is an example of a *synchronous* coroutine. In your example, the sequence code will be executed in the same thread that consumes the sequence by calling `connect()`.

#### How to delay the sequence?

As we learned, The `buildSequence` creates a *synchronous* sequence. It's fine to use regular Thread blocking here:

```
fun connect(): Sequence<T> = buildSequence {
    while (true) {
        val result = dataSource.getFirstPage()
        yieldAll(result)
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

But, do you really want an entire thread to be blocked? Alternatively, you can implement asynchronous sequences as described [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#asynchronous-sequences). As a result, using `delay` and other suspending functions will be valid.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I didn't realize I was creating a synchronous coroutine

Comment: Also seems like you can try to write: suspend { delay(DELAY) } and it will work (at least it compiles)

Comment: @AntonShkurenko It just creates and throws away a lambda, i.e. a no-op

Answer (score 2):

Just for an alternate solution...

If what you're really trying to do is *asynchronously* produce elements, you can use [Flows](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html) which are basically asynchronous sequences.

Here is a quick table:

|  | **Sync** | **Async** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Single** | Normal value `fun example(): String` | suspending `suspend fun example(): String` or `fun example(): Deferred<String>` |
| **Many** | Sequence `fun example(): Sequence<String>` | Flow `fun example(): Flow<String>` |

You can convert your `Sequence<T>` to a `Flow<T>` by replacing the `sequence { ... }` builder with the `flow { ... }` builder and then replace `yield/yieldAll` with `emit/emitAll`:

```
fun example(): Flow<String> = flow {
    (1..5).forEach { getString().let { emit(it) } }
}

suspend fun getString(): String = { ... }
```

So, for your example:

```
fun connect(): Flow<T> = flow {
    while (true) {

        // Call suspend function to get data from dataSource
        val result: List<T> = dataSource.getFirstPage()
        emitAll(result)

        // _Suspend_ for a little bit
        delay(1000)
    }
}
```